# Using the MeteorJS stack, how do I return properties of an Object using the id of that object?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I am very new(2 days) to MeteorJS so I apologize if this is basic. Here is my collection and insert statement:

```
Posts = new Mongo.Collection("posts");

...Posts.insert({
        title: title,
        body: body,
        createdAt: new Date(),
        userId: Meteor.userId()
    });
...
```

I am trying to get the title, and eventually the rest of the details of a blog post with a specific id(that a user has clicked on to view):

```
console.log(Posts.find({_id: this._id}).fetch('title'));
```

Here is what is currently being output:

```
 [Object]0: Object_id: "a6sxfuj2fzhjrLHwb"body: "Get a life Lebrec!"createdAt: Wed Apr 13 2016 22:14:17 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)title: "Lebrec makes a fifth blog post."userId: "ST4g5DHWFL3wXZLdx"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]
```

I am getting a whole object, along with other stuff. I am just looking for the title, "Lebrec makes a fifth blog post.", to be output to the console in this instance. The end goal is to display the title, date, email of user, and body of post in a modal. The modal is already functioning. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the "Find and Fetch" section of [common mistakes](https://dweldon.silvrback.com/common-mistakes). Here's what you are looking for:

```
console.log(Posts.findOne({_id: this._id}).title);
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot! This is my first MeteorJS app and it's absolutely amazing, just a lot of new stuff to learn.